# jquery - doesn't fire change function on dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created some dropdown dynamically using jquery.

And `.change()` function doesn't fires up on those dynamically created dropdown.

JS Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = {
        1:['Five', 'Six', 'Seven'],
        2:['Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten'],
        3:['Eleven', 'Twelve', 'Thirteen'],
        4:['Fourteen', 'Fifteen', 'Sixteen']
    }
    $('.dropdown1').change(function() {
        if ( $(this).val() == '-1' ) {
            ""
        } else {
            $('.dropdown2').remove();

            $('div.dropdown23').append('<select id="dropdown2" class="dropdown2">')

           $.each(data[$(this).val()], function(i, val) {
               $('#dropdown2').append('<option value="'+ val.toLowerCase() +'">'+ val + '</option>')
          })
        }
    })
    $('div.dropdown23').on('change', '#dropdown2', function(){
        alert("Yes!!")
    })
})
```

Someone please help me.

Here's the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/K7rb2/).

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Sure.... Will do it. And now I'm confused on which answer i must accept. They both gave me the same info and at the same time.\

Comment: :-) It's up to you, whichever you found most helpful. (Wow, one second apart!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As you are creating elements dynamically*

You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

i.e.

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Example

```
$('div.dropdown23').on('change', '#dropdown2', function(){
    //Your code         
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/K7rb2/4/)

> **The delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.** By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, we can use delegated events to bind the click event to dynamically created elements and also to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

Comment: I have one more doubt. Is this same way we need to use even for `hover` function?

Comment: @UnknownUser, Use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event in same manner. Also you need to know that `$( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )` is shorthand for `$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );`

Comment: Can I know the difference between `.change` and `.on('change', function())`?? One last query i have in my mind for now :)

Comment: @UnknownUser, `.change()` is shortcut for `.on( "change", handler )`,  see docs http://api.jquery.com/change/ for detail

Comment: I know it's a short method for it. But I faced some challenge on using `.change()` and `.on('change')`. But nothing is elaborated in the docs. Anyways thanks a lot.

Comment: @UnknownUser What challenge? I might help you

Comment: Like... I'm using `jquery.dropdown.js` for my dropdown. And There's and span and a text is created for the dropdown i create using html. And when I was using `$('.span').click(func...)`. The function used to execute after I select that value and again when I click on that span. But after i used `$(.span').on('click', func....)` the click is even is being fired for the first time I click itself. This was the challenge I was facing. And after I used `.on('change', func...)` by seeing yours. It's working like charm.

Comment: @UnknownUser, I think you are looking for difference between `.on('event','selector',callback_function)` and `.on('event',callback_function)`

Comment: Maybe.. But not sure. I'm a rookie.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** here since your `select` has been added dynamically to the DOM:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector,
>   whether those children exist now or are added in the future.

```
$('body').on('change','#dropdown2',function() {
    alert("Yes!!")
});
```

So basically, event delegation will help you to attach change event to this newly loaded `select`.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K7rb2/1/)**